# Using "said <person>" before quoted text

Tags: word-order

As a non native English speaker I've always found the following form strange:

```
Said Hamlet, "To be, or not to be".
```

I would more naturally say:

```
"To be, or not to be", said Hamlet.
```

Is there a stylistic difference between the two?

Comment: Inversion in the quote structure is sounding less and less natural per se.

Comment: In and of themselves there's no significant difference but in and of themselves is not the point, is it?

As the examples are written, which best fits the style of the piece they're part of?

Either way, what happens if the quotes contain the whole soliloquy?